# Cannot see wordpress widget without log in

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Thank you for your interesting I solved it by deleting the advanced cache plugin (which hosgatar install automatically). I deactivated and deleted it but there is still file on wp-uploads. I delete it and it display perfect.
I HATE THIS PLUGIN

My wordpress widget on single page isn't display to visitor ( no code on view source)

```
<div class="secondaryColumn"></div>`
```

`
the widgets are call both from front page( homepage) and single

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/second.column.post.php'); ?>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/third.column.shared.php'); ?>
```

They display normally on homepage. 
When I log in as admin I can see them on single page but they aren't displayed with unlogin user(visitor)
Unlogined user can view it normally on homepage but single page

May you help me with it?

here are my files: It's from GidFocus Wordpress theme

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ua624lq018inam/function.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/suqrlxc5sbltse4/index.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/izuzfy0xnfb8m8z/sidebar.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tspyk25f3lhxr3/single.txt
```

Comment: I added the code call widget on my post. I tried to change it to
<get template part> but it does not work too

Comment: please check in single.php where code of display sidebar is written that `is_user_logged_in()` is used or not. Check in the widget's code too `is_user_logged_in()` how this function is used.

Comment: Thank you @StreetCoder I check it all ( the code is quite short) on both single and function but I can't seem find any line check the user or user_logged_in()

Comment: Without seeing those files, impossible to say.

Comment: did you check functions.php if so please check the widget. Is widget plugins or included into the theme?

Comment: thank you for your interesting. I uploaded the code in dropbox please check it. If you need anything more to identify this problem, feel free to ask please. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your interesting I solved it by deleting the advanced cache plugin (which hosgatar install automatically). I deactivated and deleted it but there is still file on wp-uploads. I delete it and it display perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and it turned out to be a setting in the template. One thing to note is that the setting did not kick in right away. I tried the next day and it worked in the same browser.